# Search and Replace with Numbers

Tags: javascript, macos, replace

Alright so I've got list in JS formatted like so:

```
{ text:"item1here", link: "0"},
{ text:"item2here", link: "0"},
...
{ text:"item2000here", link: "0"}
```

The list has over 2,000 items in it, I need a way to get the link: "0" to match that entries number in the list, starting with 0 and going upwards. Obviously some kind of search and replace would work find. Any ideas on how to go about this? I'm on a Mac so any UNIX or OS X method would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't quite understand? you wanna match what with what?

Comment: So say item1here is the first item, I want it to say link: "0". And for the second item in the list, link: "1", and keep going throughout the entire list.

Comment: Show us what you have and how it should look like.. not just one of them.

Comment: @Peter Wouldn't that be redundant? You can easily extract the number from the text property name and just subtract 1. For example, for "item1here", you extract the number 1, and after subtracting 1, you got 0.

Comment: Not that easy, heres the actual list: http://pkazz.com/database/js/namelist.js As you can see the names don't actually contain the number. Jeff's works!

Comment: +1 for using a JavaScript database :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 perl -e '$i=0; while(<>) { if(s/link\:\s+\"0\"/link: "$i"/){ $i++;} print; }' yourfilename > newfilename
```

There are lots more ways using various UNIX commands.  Let me know if you need this explained in detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;

for (var obj in names) {
    obj.link = String(i);
    i += 1;
}
```

(this is how you would do it programmatically  in JavaScript)